# What are the differences between flutter_secure_storage and shared_prefrences in flutter? Why is flutter_secure_storage more secure?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

Actually, I've heard that for saving sensitive data, it's better to save it in flutter_secure_storage; but I found nowhere about how flutter_secure_storage is more secure than shared_prefrences? should I save the user token in flutter_secure_storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flutter_secure_storage` is stored with aes encryption but there is better option available with same security but with high performance `hive`. here you can read more about it https://pub.dev/packages/hive#benchmark